# Parsing this nested json?

Tags: python, json, nested, nmap

I am trying to parse nmap scan results converted from xml to json. Part of the json I am having troubles to extract is below:

```json
"ports": {
    "port": {
    "@portid": "22",
    "state": {
        "@state": "open",
    },
    "service": {
        "@product": "OpenSSH",
    },
    "script": [
        {
            "@output": "\n  ssh-dss AAAArO379Amw==\n  ssh-rsa AAAAB3nSb3vZeQAw==",
            "@id": "ssh-hostkey",
            "table": [
                {
                    "elem": [
                        {
                            "@key": "key",
                            "#tail": "\n",
                            "#text": "QUFBQUIzTnphQzFrYzNNQUFBQ0JBUHkzQVhaemI4N1IzRvQnh3ZWlOaJtLzc1azBsMGtVMG1ock8zNzlBbXc9PQ=="
                        },
                        {
                            "@key": "fingerprint",
                            "#tail": "\n",
                            "#text": "4724ad3b5f2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "#tail": "\n",
                    "#text": "\n"
                },
                {
                    "elem": [
                        {
                            "@key": "key",
                            "#tail": "\n",
                            "#text": "QUFBQUIzTnphQzF5YzJFQUFBQUJJd0FBQVFFQXJlZTc5cWhlNUJxQ3RPWElYbDVrbTY0azI5eHR3UStyTnRiM3ZaZVFBdz09"
                        },
                        {
                            "@key": "fingerprint",
                            "#tail": "\n",
                            "#text": "a015719c9"
                        }
                    ],
                    "#tail": "\n",
                    "#text": "\n"
                }
            ]
        }}}
```

I am trying to extract parts from script keys, my code looks like this

```
if 'script' in extracted_json['ports']['port']:
    for something in extracted_json['ports']['port']['script']['table']:
        print something['elem']
```

however, when I run it, I get back error message `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. If I try to change `print` statement to `print something[1]`, then I get this: `KeyError: 1`. How should I extract information from this nested json?

Variable *something* contains this

```
{
    u '#tail': u '\n', u '#text': u '\n', u 'elem': [{
        u '#tail': u '\n',
        u '@key': u 'key',
        u '#text': u 'QUFBQUIzTnTVaWURiMFNpdz09'
    }, {
        u '#tail': u '\n',
        u '@key': u 'bits',
        u '#text': u '2048'
    }, {
        u '#tail': u '\n',
        u '@key': u 'fingerprint',
        u '#text': u '239d68c0c083446c'
    }, {
        u '#tail': u '\n',
        u '@key': u 'type',
        u '#text': u 'ssh-rsa'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Its a dictionary <type 'dict'>

Comment: If i move it outside like you suggested then i get this error KeyError: 'script'. Maybe its hard to see in my json snippet because i stripped away bunch of stuff to shorten the sample , but "script" is under ports - port - script. I think

Comment: `script` is a JSON array, so you need to index it or loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script` contains an array, you need to loop through it. And `table` is also an array.

```
for script in extracted_json['ports']['port']['script']:
    for table in script['table']:
        print table['elem']
```

Comment: I get this

    for table in script['table']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

however, when i check type(script) on first for loop, it returns <type 'unicode'>

Comment: Ok, i think i found something, apparently for some hosts json data changes, depending on results, so i probably made a mistake on parsing them right. Most results gets parsed ok, but some messes with me, like this one with unicode type instead of dict.

Comment: It sounds like the API sometimes returns a string there instead of an array. You'll need to check the type and process it differently depending on the type.

Comment: Thank for giving me this idea. Late night tinkering clearly clouds my mind :)